# Where to put single quotes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, dynamic-sql, quoted-identifier

I am trying to execute the below statement which creates a database called service2019:

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50);
SET @dbname = 'service' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4));


EXEC (
'CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbname  + ' ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME =' + '' + @dbname +'' + ', FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\''' + '''' + @dbname + '''' + '''.mdf'''  + ', SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 100KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME =' + '' + @dbname + '_log' + ', FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\''' + '''' + @dbname + ''''+'''.ldf''' + ', SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 100KB )'
)
```

I get the correct database name and logical names. The problem is I get wrong physical names:

'service2019'.mdf

'service2019'.ldf

Could someone explain to me how these quotes actually work? There are some parts where it is clear but sometimes it becomes a challenge to figure out where to put those quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When developing Dynamic SQL, I suggest you start your efforts by making heavy use of the [`PRINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command rather than [`EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as things can (and often do) go wrong with Dynamic SQL.  Printing out your statement instead of *actually* running it will help you avoid some issues if you end up having syntactically correct code that is logically wrong.

In this specific case, I'm adding a new parameter, `@DSQL VARCHAR(MAX)`, setting that variable with the command, and printing it out, as follows:

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50), @DSQL VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @dbname = 'service' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4));


SET @DSQL = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbname  + ' ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME =' + '' + @dbname +'' + ', FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\''' + '''' + @dbname + '''' + '''.mdf'''  + ', SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 100KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME =' + '' + @dbname + '_log' + ', FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\''' + '''' + @dbname + ''''+'''.ldf''' + ', SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 100KB )'


PRINT @DSQL
```

Which outputs the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE service2019 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME =service2019, FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\''service2019''.mdf', SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 100KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME =service2019_log, FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\''service2019''.ldf', SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 100KB )
```

As you can see, you have too many quotes around `service2019` in your mdf and ldf filepaths.  Upon further investigation, it also looks like you have more string concatenations than necessary.  What I suggest you do is limit concatenations (i.e. `+`) to only the times where you transition between variables and static strings.  I'm also a fan of formatting my DSQL, so I'm also including a Carriage Return/Line Feed (i.e. `\r\n`) and Tab (i.e. `\t`) variables so your output looks a little cleaner.  Removing the unnecessary concatenations, including the formatting, and cleaning up the quotes gets me the following:

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50), @DSQL VARCHAR(MAX), @CRLF CHAR(2), @TAB CHAR(1);
SET @dbname = 'service' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4));
SET @CRLF = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SET @TAB = CHAR(9)


SET @DSQL = 'CREATE DATABASE ' + @dbname  + ' ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = ' + @dbname + ', FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\' + @dbname + '.mdf'' , SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 100KB )' 
+ @CRLF + @TAB + 'LOG ON' 
+ @CRLF + '( NAME = ' + @dbname + '_log' + ', FILENAME = ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL2014TEST\MSSQL\DATA\' + @dbname + '.ldf'' , SIZE = 10MB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 100KB )'


PRINT @DSQL
--EXEC(@DSQL)   /* <--- Uncomment out if you want to run this */
```

For more formatting suggestions, discussions of pitfalls that come with DSQL, and pretty much anything else, I'll point you to (what I consider the defacto guide on DSQL) [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).